# SOLR - What is max_concurrent_queries and max_results

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Im trying to understand the Solr documentation around the documentCache, this link has the following text https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html

"This cache holds Lucene Document objects (the stored fields for each document). Since Lucene internal document IDs are transient, this cache is not auto-warmed. The size for the documentCache should always be greater than max_results times the max_concurrent_queries, to ensure that Solr does not need to refetch a document during a request. The more fields you store in your documents, the higher the memory usage of this cache will be."

But it doesn't explain what `max_concurrent_queries` and `max_results` points to or even means? If anyone can help me understand? that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think they generally refer to "how many queries do you expect to run at the same time" and "how many documents are returned by these queries"; not any specific settings